# How to access scope variable in ES6 styled Angular Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, angular-controller

I switched to using ES6 (Babel) in my new Angular project. ES6 classes cannot have variables. How do I set my $scope variable now??

Say I have a simple controller:

```
class MainController {
    constructor ($timeout, events) {
        'ngInject';

            this.textMaker = "Hello!" //Option #1


    } // constructor

    textMaker(){            //Option #2
        return "Hello!";
    }


} 


export default MainController;
```

My html looks like (controller is aut0matically injected during build, say):

```
<h1> {{textMaker}}</h1>
```

Both Option #1 and Option#2 don't seem to work. I get a blank heading. Such a simple thing.. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `this` would only work if you have defined `controllerAs` or `as` for your controller, on the otherhand could you try injecting `$scope` and do something like this `this.$scope.whatever` (I'm not sure about this)

Comment: I have defined a `controllerAs` in my ui-router file. what should its value be? And how does it effect this?

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. The fact that you use ES6 doesn't change anything. You use `$scope` the same way as you use it with ES5. ES6 "classes" are just syntactical sugar (yet), not so much a new feature.

Comment: No, you  can't use $scope in es6, because if u inject and starts using $scope, the gulp will throw error as "Argument clash". This is because of, in ES6, 'this' is acting as $scope, but only when you have alise for controller in routing state definition for that controller.

Answer (score 9):

When you assign a value to a property of the controller, you have to use the controllerAs syntax for the controller.

1. controllerAs in router or directive:

   `controllerAs: 'mainCtrl' // in router or in directive, you still need to state the controller property`
2. controllerAs in ngController:

   `<div ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">`

Get the property in the HTML:

```
<h1> {{mainCtrl.textMaker}}</h1>
```

If you want to use `$scope`, inject it normally, and don't use `controllerAs`:

```
constructor ($scope, $timeout, events) {

    this.$scope = $scope; // assign $scope to a property of the controller, so it will be available in methods

    this.$scope.prop = 'value'; // refer to properties on the scope in the constructor or methods

}
```

Html:

```
<h1> {{textMaker}}</h1>
```

Comment: My problem was not stating the controller in template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets ellobrate a little on the answer above, for the ES6 controller class that you have, you can make functions that can change the values with binding.

Example:

```
class something{
 constructor(){
  this._Name = '';
 }
whatIsTheName(){
 this._Name = 'Unix Rox!'
}
export default something;
}
```

Then you just simply call whatIsTheName() on a click event, this is a great way to remove the $scope from all your code, it also makes your conversion to Angular 2 better if you are still on angular 1.

Cheers